# Read transformer value and safety tips

Tags: transformer, safety, pinout

I was trying to power up an old c64 without its original power supply, so i recovered a transformer from an old PC PSU.
Here's a top and a bottom view:

[Up view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ipLc2DWy8EYTXVCftfXriW4ACfcxgRn/view?usp=drive_link)

[Bottom view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14h6Kuj-jziksh7WJbcsYHmgx0SpNfSvm/view?usp=drive_link)

So I have a few Questions:
Is it Possible to know the voltage on the secondary by reading the numbers on top?(I've searched but found nothing)
I get the 2 pins on the same side for the primary, but why there are 6 pins on the other side?
Any safety tips?(I've heard that transformers are quite dangerous and I'm not trying to get a shock).
Thank, for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, not possible to read voltage on secondary based on numbers on it.

But the transformer is not a standard mains frequency transformer anyway, it's a high frequency switch mode transformer, so the output voltage depends on the switching controller anyway.

You can't use this transformer for 50 or 60 Hz mains, don't even attempt or you will burn the transformer or trip the breakers.

2. There are 6 pins on the secondary side because PC supplies make multiple output voltages with one transformer; depending on the era of your supply, 12V, 5V, -12V and maybe 3.3V.
3. Safety tips? Don't build it yourself if you do not understand what components to use and how; mains voltage is dangerous and lethal.

You can buy replacement supplies for C64. Much safer for you, and for your C64.